# What is the javascript find() function as opposed to the Array.find() method?

Tags: javascript

Obviously I know what `Array.find()` is.

However, my transpiler emitted (in the search for an 'e' in a string):

```
let /*integer*/ e = find(0X65,s);
```

but forgot to include my implementation of `find()`, so now I'm curious as to what the original is.

Everything works once I added the include, I'm not asking how to find an e in a string.

Hovering over that `find()` just says "native code". Google yields nothing but `Array.find()` for me however there is no array and no dot, so what is it?

Comment: Non-standard: [`Window.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find).

Comment: @Siguza Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar but it's kinda link-only. Someone else can gladly have the rep if they wanna explain what it does.

Comment: You can simply copy the description from MDN and say that it's a nonstandard feature.

Comment: "*my transpiler emitted*" - what is the original code? If the `find` call is not in the source, what transpiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks all, the link to Window.find was all I was curious about.

Comment: @Bergi It is my transpiler as first released 2 months ago: http://phix.x10.mx - not that I expect it will excite you but 33% of my entries on rosettacode work, just 3% do not, with 61% not yet tried. I just wanted to be sure I was not clobbering/overriding something I might later regret, which it turns out I am not.

Comment: @PeteLomax Oh so you're working on your own transpiler, and while fixing a bug (the missing include) you just got curious what `find` is when your IDE told you it's a native function?

Comment: @Bergi Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.find()` is a nonstandard function that's nevertheless implemented in all browsers except Internet Explorer. It's apparently a programmatic way to invoke the browser's interactive `Find` operation (i.e. <kbd>Ctl-f</kbd>).

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find)

Comment: FWIW its acknowledge in the specs that this method exists, we can hope it gets standardized one day. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#find-in-page